# Alternative to System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode/Decode?

Tags: .net, entities, html-entities

Is there any 'slimmer' alternative to the System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode/.Decode functions in .net 3.5 (sp1)? A separate library is fine.. or even 'wanted', at least something that does not pull in a 'whole new world' of dependencies that System.Web requires.

I only want to convert a normal string into its xml/xhtml compliant equivalent (& back).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For XML you just have to encode the characters that have a special meaning, so you could get away with something simple like:

```
public static string XmlEncode(string value) {
  return value
    .Replace("<", "&lt;")
    .Replace(">", "&gt;")
    .Replace("\"", "&quot;")
    .Replace("'", "&apos;")
    .Replace("&", "&amp;");
}

public static string XmlDecode(string value) {
  return value
    .Replace("&lt;", "<")
    .Replace("&gt;", ">")
    .Replace("&quot;", "\"")
    .Replace("&apos;", "'")
    .Replace("&amp;", "&");
}
```

Comment: My Q wasn't actually entirely clear, but that -was- my usecase. Thanks!

Comment: That `XmlDecode` doesn't even begin to cover XML's character and entity references (http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-references), nevermind `CDATA` sections etc.

Answer (score 27):

In .NET Framework 4.0, [System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.aspx) perhaps? **Do note that this class is located in System.dll and not System.Web.dll**.

Answer (score 4):

For HTML, if using .NET Framework 4.0's [System.Net.WebUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.aspx) not a viable solution, you could use this:

```
string HtmlEncode(string s)
{
    if (s == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var result = new StringBuilder(s.Length);

    foreach (char ch in s)
    {
        if (ch <= '>')
        {
            switch (ch)
            {
                case '<':
                    result.Append("&lt;");
                    break;

                case '>':
                    result.Append("&gt;");
                    break;

                case '"':
                    result.Append("&quot;");
                    break;

                case '\'':
                    result.Append("&#39;");
                    break;

                case '&':
                    result.Append("&amp;");
                    break;

                default:
                    result.Append(ch);
                    break;
            }
        }
        else if (ch >= 160 && ch < 256)
        {
            result.Append("&#").Append(((int)ch).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).Append(';');
        }
        else
        {
            result.Append(ch);
        }
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

**Reson of implementation:**

Doing a lot of Replace() on a string would be very inneficient, especially on large strings.

**Disclaimer:**

This solution was inspired by using [JetBrains dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) on the .NET Framework 4.0 System assembly.

Answer (score 1):

If possible you can "borrow" the HttpUtility class from Mono code and compile it directly a your utility assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Although encoding might seem simple, I strongly recommend to use a library that is in wide-spread use to minimize the risk of security vulnerabilities. Microsoft's [Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=051ee83c-5ccf-48ed-8463-02f56a6bfc09&displaylang=en) provides methods for Html/Xml/Javascript escaping and the respective attribute escapes and should cover most of your web needs.

Answer (score 0):

same thing as @marco except the language is powershell

```
function Invoke-HTMLEncode
{ #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779594/alternative-to-system-web-httputility-htmlencode-decode

  param($string)
  if([string]::isNullorEmpty($string))
  { 
   $return = $null
  }
  $result = [system.text.stringbuilder]::new($string.length)
  foreach($ch in $string.ToCharArray()) 
  {
    if([byte][char]$ch -le [byte][char]'>')
    {
     switch ($ch)
     {
       '<' {
         $result.append("&lt;") | out-null
         break;
       }
       '>' {
        $result.append("&gt;")| out-null
        break;
      }
      '"' {
        $result.append("&quot;")| out-null
        break;
      }
      '&'{
        $result.append("&amp;")| out-null
        break;
      }
      default {
        $result.append($ch)| out-null
        break;
      }
     } 
    }
    elseif([byte][char]$ch -ge 160 -and [byte][char]$ch -lt 256)
    {
      #result.Append("&#").Append(((int)ch).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).Append(';');
      $result.append("&#").append(([byte][char]$ch).toString([System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)).append(';') | out-null
    }
    else
    {
      $result.Append($ch) | out-null
    }
  }
  $result.ToString()
}
```